# Importing Bioconductor and GitHub Packages in R Package Development

Tags: r, package, cran, bioconductor

My problem is that i create a R package, and i have some dependencies packages that they are from Bioconductor, (actually the problem is for Caret too , which is Cran), and i get this error :

```
checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Packages required but not available:
  'SingleCellExperiment', 'SummarizedExperiment', 'caret', 'Seurat',
  'DESeq2', 'MAST', 'edgeR', 'BPSC', 'gbm', 'mRMRe', 'Kendall',

  'FSelector', 'fastshap', 'catboost', 'ranger'
Packages suggested but not available for checking:
  'knitr', 'rmarkdown', 'randomForest', 'C50', 'testthat'

VignetteBuilder package required for checking but not installed: 'knitr'

See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
manual.
```

My description file is :

```
......
License: GPL-3
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
RoxygenNote: 7.2.3
Depends: 
    R (>= 4.2.0)
biocViews:
Imports:
  SingleCellExperiment,
  SummarizedExperiment,
  caret,
  Seurat,
  DESeq2,
  MAST,
  edgeR,
  stats,
  BPSC,
  utils,
  gbm,
  mRMRe,
  Kendall,
  FSelector,
  fastshap,
  catboost,
  ranger
Remotes: 
    nghiavtr/BPSC,
    catboost/catboost
Suggests:
    knitr,
    rmarkdown,
    randomForest,
    C50,
    testthat (>= 3.0.0)
Config/testthat/edition: 3
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

The CMD check in R is done without error, but when I do the online R-hub check, I get that error I mentioned. If someone could help , will be nice ! THnaks !

I build my package, i pass the check in R studio, but when i check online (https://builder.r-hub.io/) my package.tar.gz , then i get the error i mentioned!
I would also like to mention that everything works fine when I build and install the package, and the Check in RStudio runs without any errors, warnings, or notifications.